# Редирект из локального проекта на хостинг Word Press?

Tags: wordpress, база-данных

Друзья, привет!
У меня проблема, я сделал проект на Ворд Прессе , все готово осталось залить на хостинг, я залил, но не удачно. Я поменял адрес сайта в админ панеле, и все полетело.

Вопрос в том что когда я запускаю проект на локальном меня редиректит на другое доменное имя, я пробовал 4 способа это устранить но ничего не работает, как мне убрать этот редирект на другой домен, если я не могу зайти в админку, и пока не понимаю где нужно изменить доменное имя на локальное?

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Что именно вы меняли? Есть такой файл? -> `.htaccess` 
Я вообще не знаю как можно неудачно залить проект так, чтоб на локалке редирект появился :)

Comment: Все проблемы, связанные с переносом сайта, изложены здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562